# Left delete icons not appearing while UITableview edit mode

Tags: iphone, uitableview, swipe

I have a core data/ uitableview based app. Actually 80% of the code so far is equal to the Apple Sample app CoreDataRecipes. My problem is that when I enter the edit mode (by pushing the edit button), there are no "delete badges" on the left side of the rows. Bumper.

[image]

The differences in code with CoreDataRecipes:

1. I have custom UITabelview cell with
   a nib file instead of code only.
2. My Tableview is an Outlet inside my class view. So my class
   RecipeListTableViewController is an
   UIViewController with Tableview delegates instead of a UITableViewController

What I tried:

- The Tableview works fine. There are no linking or delegate issues
- I checked if the table actually
  enters the edit mode. It does. You
  can see that because the "Add" button
  is disabled.
- I checked if the editingstyle is ok. It should be by default but to make sure I added:

  (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView*)tableVieweditingStyleForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;}
- I checked if the delete icons where not behind my cellview. There are not. I now think that the cell behaviour of moving to the right is handled by iOS.
- When I swipe the cell, the right delete button appears and works as it should
- I tried to build the behaviour my self with a layoutSubviews. Nothing changed when entering the edit mode. But when I swipe, now I see my subview in one row:

[image]

Anyone any ideas? It must be something simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return YES;
}
```

If this is not set to return YES then the badges will not be enabled.  The default is set to return NO

Comment: this defaults to true in swift

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not added the line
 `tableView.editing=YES`  on clicking the Edit button

Try by setting it!

Comment: The app crashes with: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name ... But I think that this already works with the Edit button. I use self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

Comment: hey buddy..you are going off the track..the question you posted is not having any relation with Coredata.

Answer (score 1):

Since yours is a UIViewController, the tableview doesnt get the setEditing call. Just add:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tv setEditing:editing animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have setup the outlet/ delegate/ datasource 
then these:

```
-(void)editButtonTapped
{
    [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
}



-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```